# How do I print a new row after printing the previous one with my elongated process?

Tags: python

I wrote a bunch of stuff to print out a randomly generated map of symbols and made a character move around but I need the rows to reprint with a new line each time.

I tried putting printed.insert(multiplier, "\n") in various places but it will just put like 7 \n's and then the rows so I don't know how to make it place a \n on the end of a row. I'm putting the program as is so you guys can understand what's trying to be done.

```
import random
import time
import os
def cls():
  os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
randomnumber = random.randint(6,16)
block = []
printed = []
health = 10
blocks = "\x1b[1;37;48m#"
randumplace = random.randint(0, len(block))
multiplier = 47
def build(blocks):
  for i in range (multiplier):
    block.append(blocks)
    printed.append(blocks)
    i = random.randrange(1, 75)
    if i == 4:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;31;48mM"
    elif i == 15:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;36;48m~"
    elif i == 25:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;36;48m~"
    elif i == 22:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;33;48m$"
    elif i == 1:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;37;48m#"
    elif i == 10 and "@" not in printed:
      blocks = "@"
    else:
      blocks = "\x1b[1;37;48m."
counter  = 1
print("# "+"# # # # # #" + " #" * (multiplier - 6))
while counter != randomnumber:
    del block[:]
    build(blocks)
    print(*block)
    counter += 1
print ("" + "# " * (multiplier +1))
position = printed.index("@")
while position != 38:
    movement = input("Move which direction? (Type 'help' for commands)")
    if movement == "d":
        cls()
        printed.pop(position+1)
        printed.insert(position+1, "@")
        printed.pop(position)
            printed.insert(position, ".")
        print(*printed)
        position = printed.index("@")
    if movement == "a":
        cls()
        printed.pop(position-1)
        printed.insert(position-1, "@")
        printed.pop(position)
        printed.insert(position, ".")
        print(*printed)
        position = printed.index("@")
    if movement == "w":
        cls()
        printed.pop(position-32)
        printed.insert(position-32, "@")
        printed.pop(position)
        printed.insert(position, ".")
        print(*printed)
        position = printed.index("@")
    if movement == "s":
        cls()
        printed.pop(position+33)
        printed.insert(position+33, "@")
        printed.pop(position)
        printed.insert(position, ".")
        print(*printed)
        position = printed.index("@")
```

I expect it to reprint the map with a position changed for the "@" symbol but it just makes it all together with no new lines

Comment: I don't get it. Have you tried adding "\n" at the end of the string?

Comment: I have tried putting \n at the end of it but the row of symbols is a list not a string.

Comment: seems like the first 'd' and all the 'w' aren't working. Why not keeping each line as a string, and keep all the lines in an array? Then when asking 'w', get the index of the @ in the current line, and replace the @ with another sign, then in the same index of the previous line you should place the @. Ofc that you need to check many cases when the user presses 'w' where on the first line or gets stuck in a & or whatever.